# Push a screen as a result of a redux action

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Recently tried https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/ 
As I understand one of the problems solved in v2 was **pushing a screen as a result of a redux action**. Basically I am still having doubts which is the right way to use navigator outside component.

```
export function loginUser(user, componentId) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_PENDING })

    Api.loginUser(user)
      .then((response) => {
        // success
        Navigation.push(componentId, { component: { name: 'Profile' }})

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_ERROR,
          payload: { ...err.response.data, status: err.response.status },
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Passing componentId kinda feels weird to me. How you guys do it? Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push a screen from outside of the stack's scope - You first need to assign the stack a predefined `id`, then you can easily push to it from your actions by passing the stack's id, instead of some componentId you propagate to your actions from a component.

First, assign an id to your stack:

```
const stack = {
  id: 'MyStack', // This will allow you to interact with the stack from your actions
  children: [
    {
      component: {}
    },
    {
      component: {}
    }
  ],
  options: {

  }
}
```

Then, push your screen to the stack associated with `MyStack` id:

```
Navigation.push('MyStack', {
  component: {
    name: 'MyComponent'
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work for me. Always getting the same error as in this issue https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3171

Comment: other question, where in your code would you add the push?